# Validation with Catel and quite complex object

Tags: catel

I'm trying to implement validation in the smarter way as I can...
Starting from the beginning I've a gridview with some data loaded from the DB (the object doesn't inherits from ModelBase). When a user right click on a item end edit it an edit popup appears.

That's the code that load the popup window

```
public override async Task UpdateDeal(IDeal deal)
    {
        var item = (DealForward)deal.Clone();
        var modello = viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<DealForwardUpdateViewModel>(item);



        var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
        var uiVisualizerService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUIVisualizerService>();

        await uiVisualizerService.ShowDialogAsync(modello);
    }
```

And here's the DealForwardUpdateViewModel

```
public class DealForwardUpdateViewModel : DealUpdateViewModel
{
    #region Model
    [Model]
    public DealForwardUpdateModel Model
    {
        get { return GetValue<DealForwardUpdateModel>(DealForwardUpdateModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DealForwardUpdateModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData DealForwardUpdateModelProperty = RegisterProperty("Model", typeof(DealForwardUpdateModel), null);
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [ViewModelToModel("Model")]
    public DealForward Deal
    {
        get { return GetValue<DealForward>(DealProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DealProperty, value); }

    }

    public static readonly PropertyData DealProperty = RegisterProperty("Deal", typeof(DealForward), null);

    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public DealForwardUpdateViewModel(DealForward forward, IDynamicContainer container)
    {
        this.Model = new DealForwardUpdateModel(forward);

        this.container = container;
    }
```

I'm not sure what to put in the DealForwardUpdateModel, should I put just the DealForward or do I have to explode it into it's own fields when I'm in the constructor?

```
public class DealForwardUpdateModel : ModelBase
{
    public double? Cambio { get; set; }

    public DealForwardUpdateModel(DealForward deal)
    {
        this.Deal = deal;
        this.Cambio = deal.Cambio;
    }
    public DealForward Deal
    {
        get { return GetValue<DealForward>(DealProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DealProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData DealProperty = RegisterProperty("Deal", typeof(DealForward), null);
}

[ValidatorDescription("DealForwardUpdateModel", Catel.Data.ValidationResultType.Error, Catel.ValidationType.Field)]
public class DealForwardUpdateModelValidator : AbstractValidator<DealForwardUpdateModel>
{
    public DealForwardUpdateModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Deal.Split).SetValidator(new SplitValidator());

        RuleFor(x => x.Cambio).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage(DealResources.STR_VALIDATION_CAMBIO);

        RuleFor(x => x.Deal.QtaDiv1).LessThan(0).When(x => x.Deal.Segno == 1).WithMessage(DealResources.STR_VALIDATION_NEGATIVE_QTA1);
        RuleFor(x => x.Deal.QtaDiv1).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0).When(x => x.Deal.Segno == 0).WithMessage(DealResources.STR_VALIDATION_POSITIVE_QTA1);

        RuleFor(x => x.Deal.QtaDiv2).LessThan(0).When(x => x.Deal.QtaDiv1 > 0).WithMessage(DealResources.STR_VALIDATION_OPPOSITE_QTA2);
        RuleFor(x => x.Deal.QtaDiv2).GreaterThan(0).When(x => x.Deal.QtaDiv1 < 0).WithMessage(DealResources.STR_VALIDATION_OPPOSITE_QTA2);
    }
}
```

The second option seems to work but before smashing my DealForward into a list of fields I ask if there's a better aproach.

Please consider that I've 3/4 different kind of deal and they have a sharable editable/validatable part

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can implement validation:

1. Validar (Fody plugin), like you did in your 2nd example
2. FluentValidation (Catel has an extension for this)
3. Simple validation that is available in the models / view models by overriding ValidateFields and ValidateBusinessRules

1 and 2 give a nice SoC (Separation of Concerns).

Comment: I've used 2... Since I've got a "sharable" set of fields to show validate and I've seen I can compose views with nested view/viewmodels https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Introduction+to+the+nested+user+controls+problem ... does the validation apply as well even if there're different views/viewmodels